# redis locking: redispy vs python-redis-lock

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

Except that python-redis-lock module provides contextmanager for the lock object - what are the differences when compared to the lock object you get from redispy module? what is so special about python-redis-lock?

```
rc = Redis.from_url(settings.BROKER_URL)
lock_str = "bld-%s-lock" % bld_id
```

Using redispy:

```
lock = rc.lock(lock_str)
```

Using python-redis-lock:

```
lock = redis_lock.Lock(rc, lock_str)
```

Comment: not much difference IMO, you could stick with`redispy`. `redispy.Lock` implemented (`release`) both in pipelines and Lua, with threading support, `python-redis-lock` only in Lua, but has Django integrate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the context manager is not the major difference here, because if you see code of redis-py [Lock](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/lock.py#L81) they have the `__enter__` and `__exit__` added in there.

Both the Lock's seem to use SETNX for acquiring the lock:

- python-redis-lock: [Github](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-redis-lock/blob/master/src/redis_lock/__init__.py#L228)
- redis-py Lock: [Github](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/lock.py#L126)

The major difference I saw in there was the way blocking the threads work.

- In case of **python-redis-lock** they have been using [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) mechanism to block the thread, which to me seems like using redis's own version of blocking mechanism. [Github code](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-redis-lock/blob/master/src/redis_lock/__init__.py#L233)

> Something like:
>
> `timed_out = not self._client.blpop(self._signal, blpop_timeout) and
>   timeout`

- In case of **redis-py** they seem use [time module](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/lock.py#L109) and its [sleep](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/lock.py#L118) method to block the thread to check whether the blocking has timedout.

> Something like:
>
> ```
> import time as mod_time
>
> ...
> stop_trying_at = mod_time.time() + blocking_timeout
> ...
> mod_time.sleep(sleep)
> ```